# Why are those crontab rules not working?

Tags: php, linux, cron, debian, system-administration

I'm trying to generate some report every last day of month with crontab.

Here is my rules :

```
45 20 31 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 * php console make:export > /dev/null 2>&1
45 20 30 4,6,9,11 * php console make:export > /dev/null 2>&1
45 20 28 2 * php console make:export > /dev/null 2>&1
*/2 * * * * php ..cronjobs/cron_photos_tri.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But, while every others line in the same file is working fine, those are never triggered. Here is the syslogs for the last day of 07/2018:

```
Jul 31 20:40:01 CRON[19453]: (root) CMD (php ...cronjobs/cron_photos_tri.php >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 31 20:42:01 CRON[19880]: (root) CMD (php ...cronjobs/cron_photos_tri.php >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 31 20:44:01 CRON[20248]: (root) CMD (php ...cronjobs/cron_photos_tri.php >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 31 20:46:01 CRON[20599]: (root) CMD (php ...cronjobs/cron_photos_tri.php >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

As you can see, the cron_photos_tri.php is triggered but not the make:export one. Why ?

Comment: Preferably use the absolute path for `console`

Comment: @kerbholz: It's an absolute path on the server, I simplied them in the code for reading reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need in crontab to have the command run at the every end of each month on (11:59 pm) :

```
  59 23 28-31 * * root [ $(date +\%d -d tomorrow) = 01 ] && executioncode
```

How to make a test on today (2018-08-01 23:59 pm)

```
  59 22 01-03 * * root [ $(date +\%d -d tomorrow) = 02 ] && executioncode
```

The code will execut on `2018-08-01 10:59 pm`

EXPLAINE CRON :

the `root [ $(date +\%d -d tomorrow) = 01 ]` means that if tomorrow is equal to 1 and the current day is between 28 and 31 then is mean is the last day of month

Comment: Is there any way of "trying" this without waiting for the end of the month ?

Comment: check my upate it will exaplain how

Comment: While I'm waiting 14h20 for the test. Can you tell me why my rules arn't working ?